# Fit several simple linear regressions vs single multiple linear regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I'm interested in understanding how two independent variables $X$ and $Y$ might relate to dependent variable $Z$. $X$ is categorical with 4 levels while both $Y$ and $Z$ are continuous.

Would it be better to understand how $Y$ impacts $Z$ by

1) Fitting 4 simple linear regressions: $Z = {\beta_0} + {\beta_1} Y$ (1 per factor of $X$)

or

2) Fitting 1 multiple linear regression: $Z = {\beta_0} + {\beta_1}Y + {\beta_2}X$

I'm also interested in understanding if $Y$ interacts with $X$.

My thoughts: 
    My usual approach would be to fit a model  via method 2 and then another one with their interaction and see if the model with the interaction effect fits better and if an ANOVA suggests to use the second model over the first. I'm being presented with the first type of analysis but I can't answer with why that seems fishy. Is the effect of $X$ not being controlled for method 1? My gut is also telling me why not just use one model with $X$ included as a categorical variable?

Comment: From what you say, you care about doing inference on the parameter estimates, no? Could you give context on what X and Y represent as to better understand why would someone suggest option 1?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in doing inference on $X$ and $Y$ coefficients.

$X$ represents a 'bucketed' starting score on an student assessments. $Y$ represents the amount of treatment (the main thing we are concerned with evaluating). $Z$ represents the difference or growth in assessments in starting score (pre-treatment) to ending score (post treatment).

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow entirely. If X is a starting score how come it is a factor? What do you mean by 'bucketed'? Could you expand on the context of your problem?

Comment: Also, for model 1, I assume you are fitting a model without intercept and you're using the intercept for the dummy of X, or did you miss on adding the second predictor?

Comment: As for why you feel the method 1 is fishy, you will end up with 4 different coefficients for variable Y, which makes the inference an unnecessary mess. The intercept for each of these four models reflects a mix of the other factor levels not included in the equation, and the interpretation highly likely will not be of your interest.